# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound not playing sounds

Tags: objective-c, audiotoolbox

I am playing a small .wav file using the AudioToolBox.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
```

But sometimes it is not playing.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960757/system-sound-on-iphone-not-playing/11966098#11966098) issue? `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID()` will stop the sound work before playing.

Answer (score 16):

If you're in the Simulator, make sure that in System Prefrences → Sound, that "Play user interface sound effects" is not turned off. If you're on the device, check that the ringer switch is not set to silent.

Comment: I can't find any "System Preferences". Are they in the simulated device or in the simulator application?

Comment: I mean on Mac OS X, in your computer's System Preferences.

Comment: Holy cow, that's dumb. What kind of a "simulation" mirrors the settings of its host system like this?

Comment: Another big "thanks" here; agreed, @Josh. Note, too, that this setting seems to affect only AudioServices (and maybe only AudioServicesPlaySystemSound); sounds played with the AVAudioPlayer are not affected.

Comment: NOTE: Even with headphones in the sound will not play if the phones silent switch is on, Just lost 2 hours to this.

Answer (score 3):

Building on user1056521's answer, use the following code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(soundID, ^{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
});
```

where `soundID` is the `SystemSoundID` value you got when you called `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()`.

The completion block ensures the sound was played and completed playing before it is disposed of.

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences → Sound → [x] Play user interface sound — this checkbox helped for me too, it solved the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_) issue. But worth noting was that the sample Apple Xcode project "SysSound" worked just fine without checking this box. I'm using the Xcode 4.4.1 for creating own app from scratch. Could there be differencies between projects created with older and newer Xcode tools?

Comment: The SysSound example works for the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound button but not for the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound button.  Even though they're the same sound.

Answer (score 1):

For those who visit this question later,

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundID()`'s volume is based on system Ringer in range of `0.1 ~ 1.0`, not mediaVolume

`AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundID()`'s volume is based on system Ringer in range of approximately `0.3 ~ 1.0`

Answer (score 0):

On the device, go into settings and turn up the volume on Sounds->Ringer and Alerts