# system sound on iphone not playing

Tags: ios, system, audio

I want to play a system sound but I don't hear anything:

```
- (void) play_system_sound
{
    NSLog(@"Play system sound");

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit"] pathForResource:@"Tock" ofType:@"aiff"];
    NSLog(@"path = %@", path );
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
    NSLog(@"Play system sound DONE");
}
```

I don't hear anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

After `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)` ,don't call `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID)` immediately.

Try this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit"] pathForResource:@"Tock" ofType:@"aiff"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);
}

-(void)dealloc
{ 
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

- (void)play_system_sound
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: where can i find the list of sound files in UIkit becase SentMessage.caf returns me nil?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have solved the problem, but for me, on iOS 7, sometimes the `(__bridge CFURLRef)` casting won't work, in which case, if you print out the result of `(__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]`, it will be `0x0`. This leads to failure of `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()`. The return value of the function is type of `OSStatus`. If it fails,  the function will return `-50`, which means one or more parameters are invalid. (If it executes successfully, it returns `0`.)

I solved this by using the C style function getting the path of the file:

```
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();
    CFURLRef soundFileUrl;

    soundFileUrl = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("fileName"), CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrl, &soundID);
```